# CrudRepository findById returns null mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a Databaseintem, and I have as Id a string. I created an ItemRepository and declared findById, the entry is in the database, but I get null on findById.

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

Repository:

```
@Transactional 
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, String> {
    public Item findById(String id);
}
```

Item:

```
@Entity
public class Item{
    private String id;
    private String idTrans;
    private String name;
    private Date created;
    private Date modified;

@Id
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
----
```

I have an ItemService that interacts with the repository and from ItemController I implement a rest api, get.

ItemController:

```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping(value = "/item")
   public class ItemController {

   @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
   @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK )
   @ResponseBody
   public String getItem( @PathVariable( "id" ) String id){
      Preconditions.checkNotNull( id );
      logger.info("1. getAAA " + id); // prints
      Item a = itemService.getItem( id );
      logger.info("2. getAAA " + a);
      return "a : ";// + a.getName();
   }
```

entry in DB"

```
| token1495528421393 | 2017-05-23 11:33:41 | Itemnull |               0 |        |          0 |          0 | 2017-05-23 11:33:41 |Item1
```

Request GET:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8090/item/token1495528421393
```

- item is null on findById

Comment: and your id is printed as expected by logger.info i suppose? btw shouldn't @PathVariable name be "assessment_id"?

Comment: Shouldn't the `@PathVariable` given String "id" be "assessment_id"? Have a look at [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) ... @Zeromus was faster

Comment: You got a repository for Item objects, how is that related with Assessment objects?

Comment: Sorry, is Item object, I've updated!

Comment: remove the `findById` method and use the default `findOne` method (assuming that your `id` field is annotated with `@Id`).

Comment: Doesn't work with find one either, I have @Id below the id getter.

Comment: It is because the @Id is string, i have another entity with Id Integer and works.

Comment: show your ItemService, pls

Comment: It worked finnaly, i am not sure what I changed but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run exactly in the same issue some days ago, then i have found out that the reason why this was happening was that the entity which i was retrieving had a foreign reference to another entity which thereafter had as well another foreign reference to a third entity and the latter of these [references] was configured as **not null**, but the problem was that when checking in the database the looked item had effectively a null value in the foreign key; so when the persistence framework was translating the service into a query, it was making an inner join rather than an outer join which removed the entity from the results since the join between the second and third entity was failing due to the null values.
Removing the **not null** clause in the second entity helped in fixing the issue.

Please check if your entities are not mapped in similar way.